# word2vec: vectors or projective vectors?

Tags: machine-learning

In ["Efficient Estimation of Word Representations in
Vector Space"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.3781.pdf) Mikolov et.al argue that any mapping of words into vectors should satisfy approximate constraints, such as

$vector(''Paris'') - vector(''France'') + vector(''Poland'') \approx vector(''Warsaw'')$

Then, on page 5 they choose the Cosine distance to measure the  vector proximity. Unfortunately, cosine distance is not a metric. It hints however that perhaps the problem setup has to be transferred into Euclidean Projective space. Unfortunately, there is [no identity element](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462834/is-a-projective-space-a-vector-space-if-not-what-of-a-basis) in projective space. Why the authors didn't use a conventional norm, such as $l^2$?